# React Fancy box with carousel/sliding

Tags: fancybox

In my react app, i have a problem facing related fancy box. I want to achieve UI: images in fancybox with carousel option to slide the items.

Here is the UI i need to achieve: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#gallery-1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yztvf.jpg)
I found An example of a Fancybox React wrapper in docs, but not with Carousel

````
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import { Fancybox as NativeFancybox } from "@fancyapps/ui";
import "@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css";

function Fancybox(props) {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current;

    const delegate = props.delegate || "[data-fancybox]";
    const options = props.options || {};

    NativeFancybox.bind(container, delegate, options);

    return () => {
      NativeFancybox.unbind(container);
      NativeFancybox.close();
    };
  });

  return <div ref={containerRef}>{props.children}</div>;
}

export default Fancybox;
```

https://www.fancyapps.com/resources/integration/
Can somebody help me use Carousel component in react 

i try normal Carousel in docs but not work
Here is the UI i need to achieve: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#gallery-1
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Here is a React example that combines Carousel and Fancybox - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zfff59?file=Carousel.jsx,App.tsx,style.css - hope it helps.